# What is wrong with goto command in for loop?

Tags: batch-file, goto

I have a list of computers that I want to make some things according to tcp connection status.
I'm trying to check tcp connection and if errorlog is "1" so write line to log and skip to next computer.
The problem is that when a computer has no tcp connection the `goto skip_action` command takes the script to the end and exit and the other computers in the list left unprocessed.
I have also tried to use `goto :eof` and it terminates the script unexpected.

```
ipst.txt file:
1     10.1.1.10
3     10.1.3.10
8     10.1.3.10
```

This is the batch file code:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set computerslist=ipst.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%A in ("%Computerslist%") do (
    cls
    set Station_Num=%%A
    set Comp_IP=%%B
    ping !Comp_IP! -n 1 | findstr "TTL"     
    if !errorlevel!==1 (
        echo Station !Station_Num! .... !Comp_IP! ..................... No Communication.>>%log%
        goto skip_action
    )
    echo Getting Administrator Credentials:
    net use \\!Comp_IP! /USER:WORKGROUP\****** ******
    echo.
    xcopy file.txt  \\!Comp_IP!\c\temp\
    echo Disconneting Session From Remote Computer :
    net use \\!Comp_IP! /DELETE /YES    
    :skip_action
    echo end of working on !Station_Num!
)

echo end of script
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that GOTO cancels the for loop.
But you can simply enclose your action in an ELSE block

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%A in ("%Computerslist%") do (
    cls
    set Station_Num=%%A
    set Comp_IP=%%B
    ping !Comp_IP! -n 1 | findstr "TTL"     
    if !errorlevel!==1 (
        echo Station !Station_Num! .... !Comp_IP! ..................... No Communication.>>%log%

    ) Else (
    echo Getting Administrator Credentials:
    net use \\!Comp_IP! /USER:WORKGROUP\****** ******
    echo.
    xcopy file.txt  \\!Comp_IP!\c\temp\
    echo Disconneting Session From Remote Computer :
    net use \\!Comp_IP! /DELETE /YES    
    )
    echo end of working on !Station_Num!
)
```

Comment: @Ohad_E Edit your question and add your code with the ELSE block.

Answer (score 0):

General form of if - else statement

```
   If condition (

   Statements

   ) else (

   Statements to be executed if condition is not met 

   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your call from the loop

You can have a function ping .. and parse variable references to it ..  the preceding code could also be rendered as %%a and %%b being the first and second argument respectively -- in your function call ...

```
   Call :pingcomputers %%a %%b
```

This way you avoid set altogether

```
   :pingcomputers
```

Rem Pinging computer %~1

```
   Ping %~2 ¦ find "reply"
   If errorlevel 1 goto failed
   (Actions to be performed if ping wa successful)
```

Assuming that your script has a label failed and actions to.be performed if error level is not 0 ..

Not much of a script but hope it helps ...